# Determining probability density for a Normal Distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I have the following code, which I use to obtain the graph below. How can I determine the probability density of the values as I want my Y-Axis label to be *Probability density* or,do I have to normalise the Y-values?

Thanks

```
% thresh_strain contains a Normally Distributed set of numbers
[mu_j,sigma_j] = normfit(thresh_strain);   
x=linspace(mu_j-4*sigma_j,mu_j+4*sigma_j,200);   
pdf_x = 1/sqrt(2*pi)/sigma_j*exp(-(x-mu_j).^2/(2*sigma_j^2));   
plot(x,pdf_x);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your figure as it stands is correct - the area under the curve is 1. It does not need to be normalised.
You can check this by plotting the cumulative distribution function:

```
plot(x,(x(2)-x(1)).*cumsum(pdf_x));
```

The y-axis in your figure needs to be relabeled as it is not "number of dents". "Probability density" is an acceptable label.

Comment: Thanks. But, can probability density be associated with whole numbers as it is the relative likelihood that a random variable takes on a given value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. The important limitations on probability disctributions are: 1) the values must all be positive and 2) the integral of the PDF must be 1. At any given x value, the probability distribution can have any finite positive value.

Comment: @y300 I think he's asking why there are values >1 on the y axis.

Comment: I see, thanks chappjc. In that case, maybe have a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105455/how-can-a-probability-density-be-greater-than-one-and-integrate-to-one